# How can I have Multi-line Form Labels in Sencha Touch?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

If I set a sufficiently long `label` for any kind of form element, or the `title` of a `FieldSet`, it just grows horizontally forever if I set `labelAlign` to `right`. How can I force these to wrap to the next line instead of creating horizontal scrollbars?

Comment: Also, If I force the width to be static, e.g. `width: '200'`, then it just adds an ellipsis (`...`) at the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to override the default CSS which forbids wrapping (`white-space: nowrap`). This should do the job:

```
.x-form-fieldset-title,
.x-form-label {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. If `labelAlign='left'`, then it works as expected. The fact that the behavior completely changes if `labelAlign='right' makes me think this is a bug that should be addressed by Sencha.

Comment: Odd, both labelAlign left and right makes the text ellipsis for me using 2.0 GA: http://rwd.me/FFDv (and this is expected behavior).

Comment: Ok, you're right. Maybe it was 1.x that did multi-line with left align. Shouldn't there be some setting to turn off the ellipsis? IMO, I shouldn't have to dig into the css to fix this...

Comment: Makes sense. I've added a ticket so we can implement it in the next release.

Comment: FYI; I have added it into the internal repo which means it will be in the next release of Sencha Touch (2.0.1). You'll be able to specify `labelWrap: true` on any field.

Answer (score -2):

I think using the [labelWidth](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Field-cfg-labelWidth) property for a field will give you the desired result.